# Why is my Ubuntu installation freezing?

Tags: drivers, freeze, amd-graphics

I figure this has to do with the new dramatic changes in Ubuntu recently. However, I suppose I'm more curious about knowing how to document these occurrences to find out *what* exactly is happening and then contribute these errors so that they may be fixed.

So either I'm wondering what is causing this, or how to see a log somewhere that would have these instances documented so that I may report it appropriately. I've honestly never had an Ubuntu installation freeze on me or give me so many problems. So I'm interested in helping resolve them for the greater good of the community.

My question is - how? How can I report these issues and how may I help fix it (granted there is not a solution already.)

At first, I thought it could be due to a great workload being dropped on a somewhat budget laptop. Then I realized this issue just was happening whenever.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on an HP Pavilion Laptop 17-ar0xx.

Specs are:
-AMD A10 2.5GHz x4 (APU)
-AMD Carrizo Integrated Graphics 
-8GB of RAM
-1 TB HDD @ 5400 RPM

Anything else you need to know, let me know and I'll provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standard keyboard, you should be able to type *Ctrl* and hold down the *F1* key (simultaneously).

You should then see a screen prompting you for:

- A userid
- that userid's password

if you don't see that information on your screen, keep cycling through the different  (where "x" = the number of the *Function key* at the top row of your keyboard).

During some installations, you can "cycle" much in the same way as above and you'll see install-related output.

HTH

~Rick

Comment: And how is that supposed to 'unfreeze' Ubuntu ?

Comment: it won't "unfreeze" Ubuntu but it *will* give you more details as to what might be *freezing* the install.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be sure to look into this. Gotta keep pushing for the success of this OS